# ¿Como hago para traer la fecha del mes actual de dos tablas?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, date

como andan, tengo dos tablas separadas relacionadas que insertan la fecha actual del registro, una es mes de compra y la otra es mes de pago, con la sentencia WHERE puedo traer el mes actual de una sola tabla pero no consigo traer las dos juntas, estoy usando:

```
WHERE MONTH(fecha_compra) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())"
```

si pongo:

```
WHERE MONTH(fecha_compra AND fecha_pago) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())"
```

no trae nada.

Alguien que ya trabajo con fechas que me podria ayudar?

Gracias a todos

Comment: ¿Has probado con "WHERE (MONTH(fecha_compra) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) AND (MONTH(fecha_pago) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))"? Eso de hacer un AND de dos fechas no está muy claro qué va a devolver.

Comment: Esto no existe en SQL... MONTH(fecha_compra AND fecha_pago)... es campo = valor... o sea, pone un campo y despues el otro campo, igualalos al mes y listo...

Comment: Si, lo probe "WHERE (MONTH(fecha_compra) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) AND (MONTH(fecha_pago) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))"? por las dudas pero nada, me salta error

Comment: Tambien probe WHERE MONTH(fecha_compra), MONTH(fecha_pago)  = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())" me salta error

Comment: ¿Como estas relacionando las dos tablas? ¿podrias mostrarnos la consulta completa?

Comment: $base = "SELECT empleados.id_empleado, empleados.nombre_empleado, empleados.area_id, empleados.f_compra, novedad.cargo, novedad.fechaactual, novedad.id, area.nombre_area, area.id_area FROM empleados LEFT JOIN novedad ON novedad.id_empleado=empleados.id_empleado INNER JOIN area ON empleados.area_id=area.id_area WHERE MONTH(novedad.fecha_pago) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);

Comment: Asi me muestra solo fecha_pago, y quiero que me muestre las dos fechas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz dos consultas y únelas con `UNION` o utiliza `FROM tabla1, tabla2` con las condiciones and separadas `WHERE (MONTH(fecha_compra) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) AND (MONTH(fecha_pago) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()))`

Comment: EXCELENTEEEEEE!!! Muchas gracias a todos por el aporte